# Sales Callers Asking for My Manager's Voicemail?

Tags: offices

So I am the receptionist at a high school and we get a lot of sales/promo calls. Many times it will happen that I do the typical call screening and when I say that "the person that handles that dept.(or the specific person, if they know who they are trying to get to) is not available, can I take a message?" They will then frequently say, "just transfer me to their voicemail" or another variation of that. No one likes to have their voicemail bogged down with useless sales calls. It is especially aggravating when it is for the head of the school, as he obviously has no time for sales calls and does not even want them transferred to his voicemail, understandably. So I am trying to come up with a way to get around this, maybe change what I say from the beginning, so that it removes the opportunity for them to request the person's voicemail. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this or do you have something that works for you?

Comment: They haven't really given me much. They were the ones that initially said to tell them "so and so is not available, can I take a message" and I've mentioned that then they often just ask for voicemail and they said something to the effect of, "not sure, we'll have to think of something"

Comment: Do you actually pay any attention to sales calls? If not, state that you don't take sales calls at that school, but politely thank them for their time. If they keep persisting, warn that you will hang up, and if they keep persisting more then do so.

Comment: If it helps any, remember that sales callers spend their whole day being told to get lost. I'm not suggesting you go out of your way to be rude, but equally, you shouldn't let them abuse your concern for their feelings.

Comment: "No sales calls. Please don't call again. Goodbye." <hang up>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to call another HS receptionist in your area and ask what their policies and responses are.

> Many times... when I say that "the person that handles that dept... is not available, can I take a message?" They will then frequently say, "just transfer me to their voicemail"

Just handle it professionally.
Your callers will try to push their way in, because that is what good sales people do.

Just say:

> I'm sorry, their voice mail isn't available right now.
>   Would you like to leave your name, your company, and a brief message?

Because their voice mail **isn't** available; at least it isn't available to *that* caller.

If they ask another question, or they are rude... just ignore it and say:

> Is there anything else I can do for you?

Comment: I really like that suggestion about saying that their voicemail is not available, that's a good way to not let them leave a voicemail without being rude. Thanks for the tip, I will definitely use that.

Answer (score 5):

It’s very simple really. When they request the person’s number, you answer with a complete sentence: “No.” Don’t give them anything. It’s psychology: If you tell them a few times that there is no way they get what they want, they give up. The slightest hint they have a chance and they will try harder.

Comment: This is correct, if your boss does not want these types of calls transferred simply refuse if they request.

Comment: I gave +1 because I agree with the sentiment, but to be slightly less abrupt, I would simply repeat “I would be happy to take a message.” If they repeat gimme voicemail, I would say “No.”

Answer (score 4):

> "the person that handles that dept... is not available"

This sounds partially like a polite fiction - the issue is not so much that they are not available *now*, the issue is that their time is not available to unscreened callers, period.

Instead of the simple "not available" (or perhaps in reply to their voicemail request) perhaps you could say something such as "please describe to me what you wish to speak with x about, and I will pass that along for their consideration".  You could optionally add (at least if there is some truth) that "x prefers not to use voicemail".  Or even simply start by stating that preference, and if they still insist restate it as a firm matter of policy: "I am sorry, but x does not use voicemail"

Of course this is inherently somewhat hostile - you would not take this track with someone who is an existing contact, or someone your boss (or others for whom you screen calls) have been seeking to get into communication with.  Ultimately you likely need to have a discussion with others in your organization to define your policy.

But it does sound very much like keeping cold sales calls from wasting people's time is part of what you are being asked to do, so you should develop a strategy for it.  Ages ago I was at a party where someone who was administrative assistant who spent a lot of time trying to keep cold calls from leaking through, and someone in sales who spent a lot of time trying to get through to principles, were comparing notes on strategy, and trying to figure if they'd ever "done battle" with each other.

Comment: That's a good way to phrase it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just set up a free Google Voice account that you'd transfer calls into. [Google Voice](https://voice.google.com/) transcribes the voice mail in real-time and sends the transcript via email.

And when the principal takes a look at his voice mail, he can just take a look at them visually and batch delete them through the Google Voice web interface or through the mobile application on his phone.

Answer (score -2):

How about talking to your tech department and setting up voicemail for these types of calls?

Then you can schedule a bt of time to listen and screen the messages left there, maybe once in a blue moon you will get an interesting offer :)

Comment: It's a prep school, there's only a little over 100 students, the tech dept is anyone that has a little time and extra hands lol.The only issue is that they aren't always overt sales calls, it could be a local business and we are in a small town. So it's not a situation where I verbally let them know that I know they are trying to sell something. So I can't just flat say "no". It has to be a more subtle, tactful way of not letting them get past.

Comment: @katyp93  I didn`t suggest saying "NO". Even at the lowest technical level you have a switchboard and at least one person taking care of it. Setting up new voicemail inbox shouldn't take long

Comment: Sorry! I meant the comment about saying "no" to be to the comment above. Okie dokie thanks for the info on the setting up a new voicemail.